# Cached ResourceManager instance request — how to convert the code to Nemerle

Tags: nemerle

C# CODE :

```
[global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
        get {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("splashscreen.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
                resourceMan = temp;
            }
            return resourceMan;
        }
    }


    internal static ResourceManager : System.Resources.ResourceManager {
        get {
            when (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                mutable temp : System.Resources.ResourceManager = System.Resources.ResourceManager("splashscreen.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
                resourceMan = temp;
            }
            resourceMan
        }
    }
```

is it enough ?

Comment: I need it on Nemerle :P
even string [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)] cause error :(

Comment: There is no keyword "global" in Nemerle.

Comment: But why this string give no error then[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()] :S

Comment: and can I use it then ... without global ?

Comment: That attribute does produce an error, since :: is the list construction operator in Nemerle. Also, I recommend looking up what "global" means in MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;

// ...

[ EditorBrowsableAttribute(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced) ] 
internal static ResourceManager : Resources.ResourceManager 
{ 
    get
    { 
        when (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null))
        {
            resourceMan = Resources.ResourceManager
                ( "splashscreen.Properties.Resources"
                , typeof(Resources).Assembly
                ); 
        }
        resourceMan; 
    } 
}
```